# Get current location in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using  telnet to the Android emulator and use the geo command to send GPS coordinates to the emulator:

```
C:\>telnet localhost 5554
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix -82.411629 28.054553
OK
```

While I am running the around me application in my emulator, it is showing  a places only for above   co-ordinates....i had changed the geo fix for some other place but it will not retrieve. I want to show for some other place, what should i do in the geo fix?

Answer (score 0):

open your `emulator control` and then at bottom you can see `Location Controls` and select `Manual` tab and then click `Decimal` option --> enter `longitude` and `latitude` value of location you want to show and finally click `send` button. At the time of clicking send button your map application keep running.